# How to delete a long running Job By Job lD in Laravel 5.8 (Redis)?

Tags: php, laravel, redis

How can I delete a long running job by job id in Laravel 5.8 or PHP?

Note: its delay is set to 2 years

Environment:
Laravel 5.8
PHP 7.3

Comment: It depends what the underlying queue storage is but I would say it's safe to assume by then you'll probably end up clearing the underlying queue storage for other reasons anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can restart the worker from the forge CLI

See this

```
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues
```

and use

```
php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty
```

Comment: I need to delete Job By ID, Where we pass ID here?

Comment: I found it. zRemRangeByScore - https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#zremrangebyscore-zdeleterangebyscore-zremoverangebyscore